# Return with a for loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

The code I am using is below. As far as I am aware the logic of the code is fine but when the return is after the print for the char B then the I within the for loop wont increment. If I remove the return statement then the for loop will increment as I wanted it too, however I need the method to end if the B/W is printed so I need the return to be present. Any help is greatly appreciated I've been trying to work out whats wrong for hours now.

```
if(currentCodeString.contains("" + currentGuessChar)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + i);
            //System.out.println(currentGuess[i] + " - " + currentCode[i]);
            if(checkPins(currentGuess[i], currentCode[i])) {
                System.out.print("B");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("W");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Why need to increment if you have already found 'B'? (if that was the intended purpose). Not sure of exact scenario, so can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why are you bothered about whether `i` is incremented or not?. `i` is a local variable whose scope is limited to the loop.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Should you be using `break` instead of `return`?

Comment: What you want to actually perform ? Pls explain your question clearly .Also, you can see usage of  Continue, BREAK(in a loop), Return in a method.

Comment: I have two strings, and they will be compared together and if they have the same char in the same position in the string then the B would be printed, if it is in the String but is not in the correct position then the W would be printed.

Comment: @maverick you may use the logic, check for all the matching characters and store their location. If location in two string is same print B else print W

Comment: @maverick you have written, if current char in both string matches print "B" and return. Which is not as per your question.

Comment: Ive input the two strings into the method and then put them into a char array and then moved through the array to see if a B needs to be printed, as then if the if statement is true then they are in the same position that follows right?

Comment: @maverick yes, if they are in same position that will be check for only first time as per your program and then your program break;

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` instead of `return` in your for loop.

```
if(currentCodeString.contains("" + currentGuessChar)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + i);
            //System.out.println(currentGuess[i] + " - " + currentCode[i]);
            if(checkPins(currentGuess[i], currentCode[i])) {
                System.out.print("B");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("W");
        return;
    }
```

`return` means - "end method", `break` means - "end loop"

Comment: He need to return if either 'B' or 'W' is found. Not sure how printing both 'BW' is helping here. Why remove return from the for loop?

Comment: All he needs is another `if` statement to check for B.

Comment: if he wants to print B, so his initial code is correct, or does he want to print B many times??

Comment: The code needs to print either B,W or nothing then end the method.

Comment: @AzatNugusbayev Initial code appears to be fine. Not sure what the issue is here really.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `return` statement with `break` after you print "B".

Comment: I tried the break but it doesnt seem to be working either, the code was working as i intended as of last night but this morning it wouldnt work and ive narrowed it down to this for loop not incrementing. It will always compare the 0 element in the array to the other 0 element in the other array instead of going through all 0,1,2,3 upto the codeLength.

Comment: @maverick if use break then also it will check for first character only and then it will  break from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

why you doesn’t use "Break" Instead of "Return"?
when the B print , Break it!

the use of return in Thread programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (without break, which i don't like)

```
if(currentCodeString.contains("" + currentGuessChar)) {
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < codeLength && !found; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + i);
            //System.out.println(currentGuess[i] + " - " + currentCode[i]);
            if(checkPins(currentGuess[i], currentCode[i])) {
                System.out.print("B");
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            System.out.print("W");
        }
    }
```